# Why is my selector ( a:hover ~ a ) not working as intended?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

What I'm trying to accomplish is when I hover over a link, it will make the other links `opacity: .1` while keeping that link color the same.

What I tried doing is `a:hover ~ a`, but it isn't working.  I created a new jsfiddle with a basic `<a href="">` and it works fine but I'm not understanding why this isn't.

http://codepen.io/jzhang172/pen/OMRqpK

```css
    @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed");

    *{
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html{
     background: url('img/congruent_pentagon.png');
    }

    body{

    margin:0px;
    }
    #wrapper{
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-top: 2em;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        height: 700px;
        background: transparent;
        font: 25px/24px normal 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
    }

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .social{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        margin-right: 16px;
        background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 0.6);
        box-shadow: 8px 8px 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }

    nav{
     padding-top: 8px;
     padding-left: 8px;
     padding-right: 8px;
 }

 nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

nav ul li a.email{
 border-left: 50px solid #c9182c;
 color: #c9182c;
}

nav ul li a.twitter{
    border-left: 50px solid #00a0d1;
    color: #00a0d1;
}

nav ul li a.facebook{
    border-left: 50px solid #365998;
    color: #365998;
}

nav ul li a.github{
    border-left: 50px solid #4183c4;
    color: #4183c4;
}

nav ul li a.google{
    border-left: 50px solid #db4a39;
    color: #db4a39;
}

nav ul li a.instagram{
    border-left: 50px solid #634d40;
    color: #634d40;
}

nav ul li a.tumblr{
    border-left: 50px solid #34526f;
    color: #34526f;
}

nav ul li a.scriptogram{
 border-left: 50px solid #0088cc;
 color: #0088cc;
}
nav ul li a.linkedin{
    border-left: 50px solid #0e76a8;
    color: #0e76a8;
}

.container{
    width:100%;
    
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;

    
}
.container h1{
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size:55px;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    font-weight:0px;

}
.container span{
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25px;f
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#0B437D;

}


a.tumblr:hover ~ a.social{
    opacity:.1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="social tumblr" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/svg/home.svg">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="social google" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/svg/prod.svg">Products</a></li>
      <li><a class="social google" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/svg/about.svg">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="social facebook" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/svg/fb.svg">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a class="social twitter" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/svg/twitter1.svg">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a class="social instagram" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/svg/insta.svg">Instagram</a></li>
      
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, you can't achieve the effect you want with the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) (`~`).

However, I think the effect can still be achieved with pure CSS. Try this:

```
ul:hover li:not(:hover) { opacity: .1; }
```

[**Revised Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQpZYx)

---

*Explanation*

`li:not(:hover)` will match all list items that are not hovered. But we can't use this alone, because then all list items will have `opacity: .1` by default.

So we begin the selector with `ul:hover`, which creates a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors) saying: *don't apply `li:not(:hover)` unless the `ul` is hovered first*.

Answer (score 2):

The general sibling combinator (`~`) matches **siblings**, your links are not siblings.

The list items containing them are siblings, which makes the links themselves *cousins*.

There is no way to describe a relationship between the links using CSS (there is no parent combinator).

The closest you can come would be to use `li:hover ~ li > a`.

Answer (score 1):

> What I tried doing is a:hover ~ a, but it isn't working. I created a
>   new jsfiddle with a basic  and it works fine but I'm not
>   understanding why this isn't.

General sibling combinator selector `~` selects elements that have same parent element.

> [8.3.2. General sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)
>
> The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

At

```
a.tumblr:hover ~ a.social {
    opacity:.1;
}
```

`a.social` elements do not have same `li` parent as `a.tumbler` element

Comment: Try using `li:first-child` , `li a.social` selectors `li:first-child:hover ~ li a.social{
    opacity:.1;
}` codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQpZzx

Answer (score -2):

So, you're trying to do something similar to this :

```
a:hover, li>a.social{
opacity: .1;
}
```

With all the "a elements" already visible and then the "hovered" element triggering the others to "disappear"